# NSUserdefault not working with PFObject

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsuserdefaults

I'm making an chat application, with `JSQMessagesVC`. What I'm trying to achieve is, when the user hits te chat button, it will automatically show the latest chat conversation. I thought that `NSUserDefault` would be a good way to achieve this.

In the the MessageVC I've wrote an last conversation load when the user comes from a specific segue.

```
func loadLastMessage() {
    lastRooms = [PFObject]()
    lastUsers = [PFUser]()

    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "user1 = %@ OR user2 = %@", PFUser.currentUser(), PFUser.currentUser())

    let roomQuery = PFQuery(className: "Room", predicate: pred)
    roomQuery.orderByDescending("lastUpdate")
    roomQuery.includeKey("user1")
    roomQuery.includeKey("user2")

    roomQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            self.lastRooms = results as [PFObject]

            for room in self.lastRooms{
                let user1 = room.objectForKey("user1") as PFUser
                let user2 = room["user2"] as PFUser

                if user1.objectId != PFUser.currentUser().objectId {
                    self.lastUsers.append(user1)
                }

                if user2.objectId != PFUser.currentUser().objectId {
                    self.lastUsers.append(user2)
                }
            }

            let user1 = PFUser.currentUser()
            let user2 = self.lastUsers[0]

            let pred = NSPredicate(format: "user1 = %@ AND user2 = %@ OR user1 = %@ AND user2 = %@", user1, user2, user2, user1)

            let roomQuery = PFQuery(className: "Room", predicate: pred)
            roomQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (results:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    let room = results.last as PFObject

                    let roomObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(room)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(roomObject, forKey: "kamer")

                    let userObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(user2)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userObject, forKey: "andereUser")

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try `unarchiveObjectWithData` as a `PFObject` It gives me a crash!

`-[PFUser setObject:forKey:] 0x10ac19a9a:  movq   0xb709f(%rip), %rsi       ; "isEqualToString:"`

I think it has something to do with casting but still I have not found the solutions. When I `println` the NSData before unarchiving it shows me the data.

Comment: What about using the Pinning from parse (local datastore) ?
If you think it's a good way I'll post an example how to save your objects in the localdatastore.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RaVeN , only thing is it takes to long to load. I've tried it and the app will crash due nil value for certain PFObjects

Comment: parse localdatastore is really fast and it's more compatible with PFObjects because you don't need to fill the PFObjects in other objects which you can save into your NSUserDefaults.
see this: http://blog.parse.com/learn/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shall show more specific code about `NSKeyedUnarchiver` block. So I can just recommend you some advices.

- Check if the `roomObject`, `userObject` are unarchived as the correct `Class`.

Like

```
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if var user = defaults.dataForKey("andereUser") {
        user_1 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(user) as? PFUser }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because PFObject doesn't implement NSCoding Protocol, so you can' t save it to NSUserDefaults.